# Elementary Set Theory - Relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, relations

I'm not exactly sure what to search for this problem I'm having, as I don't know the keywords, so I figured the best action would be to ask a question.

I have this question:

`"Consider A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}. Let R be the relation "x divides y (xly) IF and ONLY IF there exists an integer z such that xz = y.`

Write R as a set of ordered pairs."

Firstly, where it says "x divides y (xly), should this be (xly) or (x|y)? I am more inclined to believe it should be (x|y), but i'm not sure.

I'm not exactly sure how I can get the relation. Can someone help me out, and tell me how you did it?

Thanks.

Comment: On your first question, you're right, it should be $x\mid y$, which is standard notation for "$x$ divides $y$". You can get this vertical bar with appropriate spacing around it using the $\TeX$ command `\mid`. (On this site, math formatting will be applied to anything you enclose in dollar signs; single dollar signs for inline formulas and double dollar signs for displayed equations.)

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $6×6 = 36$ ordered pairs in $A×A$.
Just write them down in a structured way and strike out all the pairs which don’t satisfy the relation.
And then $R$ is what is left.

And $x \mid y$ means that $x$ divides $y$, e.g $2 \mid 4$ and $2 \mid 6$, but $3 \nmid 4$.

Let me clarify some points: $R$ is a relation, which you can interpret in two ways:

- formally $R$ is a subset of $A × A$, i.e. $R ⊂ A×A$, and
- intuitively it’s condition by which you call an element $x ∈ A$ related to some other (not necessarily different) element $y ∈ A$.

The order is important. If $x$ is related to $y$ by condition $R$, one often writes $xRy$.

And in your definition, an element $x ∈ A$ is related to $y ∈ A$ by $R$ if and only if $x$ divides $y$, or more formally $xRy :⇔ x \mid y$ or even more formally $(x,y) ∈ R :⇔ x \mid y$ or maybe even $R := \{(x,y) ∈ A×A;\; x\mid y\}$.

These are all definitions of your relation $R$. You have to figure out, what $R$ looks like, i.e. write $R = \{ (1,6), … \}$. (Since $1 \mid 6$ you have $(1,6) ∈ R$, but what else is in there? Fill out for the dots.)

Comment: Okay, so let me try and wrap my head around this... Where it says "x divides y", these can be substituted with any variable name, a | b, or q | t, they're all the same? Furthermore, since it says x divides y, this suggests there will only be two elements in eacher ordered pair R = {(x, y), (x, y), (x,y)}, right? And "x divides y" implies that y/x will return an answer with NO remainder, and as such "x divides y" or in other words "y is divisible by x" (it can be read backwards like that??) << if that is true it would be easier for that to stick in my head. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t understand your questions and conclusions, but I edited my answer hoping this might help you.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot; I think I understand you. I made an example, could you please check it, and tell me if my logic and reasoning is correct?

http://pastebin.com/WK33fHgZ

Thanks.

Comment: @Anteara: No, more like: http://pastebin.com/2CJptABv – also be aware that the power set $P(A)$ of $A$ isn’t the same as the cartesian product $A×A$ with itself.

Comment: Oh! so simple... I was working under the assumption that I couldn't have duplicates, that is, (10,5) was the same as (5,10). It seems so simple now, thanks :). P.S. Is it only the power set in which you need to include the empty set, and itself? I would assume so, as you didn't include them in the Cartesian product, though still got the correct amount of elements.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fGCDQd81 I worked it out on my original question, and I believe I'm correct. Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, the pairs where a divides b are ...

(1,1), (1,2) ... (1,6)

(2,2), (2,4), (2,6)

(3,3), (3,6)

(4,4)

(5,5)

(6,6)

That's all they want, I think.